# Un-grey Attachments in Opportunities

Tags: attachment

How do I enable this Attachment? Right now it's greyed out. What are the steps to enable this feature so I can upload an attachment upon creating a new opportunity? 
[image: example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the standard [Notes and Attachments](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=notes_add.htm&language=en_US) related list. You are referring to a custom **Section** on your **Page Layout**, which is nothing more than a grouping of fields.

Comment: I just want to attach a files to an Opportunity Record, but there is no option to when creating or editing an Opportunity. What are the steps in Page Layout to add Notes and Attachments? I cannot find the option anywhere.

Comment: Just edit the page layout, click on **Related Lists** and drag the **Notes and Attachments** on the page layout and save. You cannot add an attachment while creating or editing a record this way, you first need to save the record and add the attachment afterwards.

Comment: That Makes Sense. I didn't know you couldn't attach a file while creating an Opportunity.